# How to resolve "You are not running your eclipse instance with java 8" for JavaFX in Eclipse Mars 2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

The error "You are not running your eclipse instance with java 8" appears after installing javaFX in Mars 2.0 on a Windows computer, and states the plugin is shut off because of this. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to resolve the "You are not running your eclipse instance with java 8" issue for Eclipse Mars 2.0, is to:

- 1: Go here [the place to download java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). It has the number then u for update, and then number for whatever update after it. Eg. I downloaded "Java SE Development Kit 8u171".
- 2: Find the newly downloaded application and run it. Eg. I found where I saved "jdk-8u171-windows-x64".
- 3: During installation there dosen't need to be any changes made to the wizard or preferences set, just keep clicking next and agreeing to things.
- 4: When the installation is done, open Eclipse, and you should see the error no longer appears. If you go to File > New > Other the folders presented will now include a folder called JavaFX, from which you can click on, and choose JavaFX project to make a new JavaFX project.